# HTML - CSS Link Order

Tags: html, css

I came across css link orders in a html file from CodeCademy. I just can't get the logic of linking css files. Why do we have to link the files according to this order below? Is it somehow related to programming where we must first define the header file which contains the functions before using them? Is that logic applicable at linking a CSS file too? Could someone please provide a comprehensive explanation for this question? :D

```html
<head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    
</head>
```

Does the order of attributes matter inside the link element? For example `<link href="" rel=""> and <link rel="" href="">`, what's the effect of having href as precedence compared to rel?

Comment: The order of the CSS file is important in the case at least two of them define the same rule but with diferent values. The last one will be applied

Comment: On a side note. This might help you. Research CSS specificity. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: btw does the order of attributes matter inside the link element? For example <link href="" rel=""> and <link rel="" href="">

Answer (score 5):

From [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order):

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.

Order matters, because, when rules conflict, order is a factor in deciding which one wins.

Comment: btw does the order of attributes matter inside the link element? For example <link href="" rel=""> and <link rel="" href="">

Answer (score 4):

Later rules override earlier rules (if they're equally specific). For example, if one CSS file does:

```
a { color: red; }
```

and a later one does:

```
a { color: black; }
```

your links will be black.

As a result, typically, you'd include the various frameworks you're using first, with your applications's CSS as the last file. This allows you to override their styles as desired.

Comment: btw does the order of attributes matter inside the link element? For example <link href="" rel=""> and <link rel="" href="">.

Comment: @IrrationalCoder No, they don't generally matter. The only situation they might matter is if you had conflicting CSS rules targeting attribute values like `input[type="text"]` but that should be very rare.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the cascade nature of a stylesheet, the latter styling overwrite the earlier styling.

For example, if there are two selectors with different `height`, the latter specified one wins.

Lets say we have:

```
#div {
    height:50px;
}

#div {
    height:100px;
}
```

The height of the `#div` will be `100px` not `50px` because `100px` is declared later. Therefore, it over-writes `50px`.

Comment: btw does the order of attributes matter inside the link element? For example <link href="" rel=""> and <link rel="" href="">

Comment: Yes the attribute declared the most recent over writes others