# Side navigation does not work when I use external CSS but does work with internal CSS in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS. As I'm trying to create my portfolio website. I run into a couple of problems that I have not been able to figure out yet. When I was coding a side animated navigation bar and used internal CSS in HTML the side navigation worked well. However, as I take the advice of other people, putting CSS code into a separate CSS file. My navigation bar has stopped working as it's intended. I've been trying to check the path of the CSS file and even moved the  path to the head but it didn't work either. I hope you guys can give me a hint on this one as I'm not sure what I did wrong. Thank you all
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="portfolio.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
title>Nin</title>
</head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">about me</a>
        <a href="#">contact</a>
        <a href="#">projects</a>
        <a href="#">resume</a>
    </div>
    <span style="color: white; font-size:30px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav() ">&#9776</span>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

JS

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px"

}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0"

}
```

Comment: I'm not using a framework because I'm totally new to HTML and CSS so I was trying to get my hand on the languages themselves first and I have not learned how to use framework yet

Comment: ..comment deleted. Use bootstrap instead. You can not write whole page full website with your CSS skill, as you've a professional expertise. And for learning CSS, you could try building your website. And look in the examples, do not ask trivial questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe my answer is not useful for you. first of all

I am looking in your code at `<link>` position, you should move this code before end of

i have small example for you

`<head>` 
`<meta></meta>` 
`<title>your title </title>`
`<link your css or another font here/>` 
`</head>`

then I think your code is working properly, I was try at 3 times and use bootstrap framework for test inserting another css.

```js
    function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px"

}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0"

}
```

```css
body{
background: #333 !important;
}
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<!-- end of bootstrap -->

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">about me</a>
        <a href="#">contact</a>
        <a href="#">projects</a>
        <a href="#">resume</a>
    </div>
    <span style="color: white; font-size:30px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav() ">&#9776</span>
```

iam adding new property in your css (body), iam setting the background is #333. for make sure your burger icon is show properly.

> IMPORTANT 
> usually if you're using framework or library CSS like bootstrap, semantic, etc the class name that you set before in your own CSS maybe can be replaced or maybe overwritten with framework or library that you use. 
> so make sure youre check is that class was set before
> or
> you can swap the position of your css [here its the discussion if you want to read about css order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611684/html-css-link-order)

Comment: I used bootstrap to implement the nav bar and it worked. Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

The external css is working on my end. The only problem is its color is white.
You can change the color in your html file of the span component.

```
<span style="color: black; font-size:30px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav() ">&#9776</span>
```

Use exact path or put your files in same folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="portfolio.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Nin</title>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">about me</a>
        <a href="#">contact</a>
        <a href="#">projects</a>
        <a href="#">resume</a>
    </div>
    <span style="color: black; font-size:30px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav() ">&#9776</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My CSS file is in the same folder along with my HTML file. I'm not sure how it worked on your end but my end is showing me the (about me, contact, projects, resume) on top of my navigation icon which I do not know why it's like that either